# Is there a way to praise the action rather than the intelligence or strength?

Tags: expressions

Considering: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/11556/2221

> Kids who are constantly told, "You are so beautiful" can actually
>   become overly worried when their looks change and become overly
>   critical of themselves.
>
> Kids that are constantly told, "Wow you are so smart" can often find
>   themselves fearful of letting the whole world see they aren't smart by
>   answering something with a "wrong" answer. They then won't try things
>   for fear of failure.
>
> Kids who have their physical attributes (such as strength, speed,
>   coordination) commented on frequently, "Wow you are so strong, that is
>   amazing" can have similar responses too - they stop trying athletic
>   activities out of concern they won't be the best at whatever it is.
>
> Kids that get used to constant compliments also start to take the
>   absence of a compliment as a failure. Which puts you in a position
>   where just because you didn't notice your child picked up two toys
>   without a reminder, you are sending a "bad" message by not commenting
>   on this good act.
>
> This means that instead of giving compliments, your default should be
>   to talk to the child about what they think. In a small child, that
>   might be something like, "wow, it looks like wearing that dress makes
>   you feel really good." or, "How did throwing the ball that far make
>   you feel?" Of course, mixing in an actual compliment here and there
>   won't hurt, just be careful not to overdo it.

The infant is 1 year old.

*When I tell her "Give me the ball", she looks for the ball, picks it up and gives it to me.

When I tell her "Pull baba's hair", she looks for her father and pulls his hair.

When I tell her "Where is the fan?", she points at the roof.

When I tell her "Where is the pigeon?", she goes to the balcony to find them.*

***Now, I do NOT want to praise her intelligence.

What is the one-word for praising the above mentioned acts?***

Comment: I'm not sure there are any verbs meaning *to praise [**any** specific thing]* - not "intelligence", and certainly not  "vocabulary". Is that really the kind of word you're looking for, or do you mean something more "general", like *praise [in order to encourage repetition of the praised behaviour]*?

Comment: Do you know that there is a single word for this and is on the tip of your tongue, or are you just hoping there might be one?

Comment: @Mitch I am not a native english speaker and I don't know anything.

Comment: actually, I wanted to praise the fact that at such a young age she can identify and remember a ball, lizard, fan, and finally understand "statements" like 'pull baba's hair'. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @ TheIndependentAquarius: Yes, but why don't you want to simply use the word ***praise***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The act you wish to praise is her *comprehension*.

One (of many) problems with seeking single words to express every concept is that you may alight on a word that is outside your audience's current vocabulary.

To praise the actions, not the personal attributes, I'd say *"Well done, you **understood** everything I asked"*

What you might want to express is *"Well done, you **showed me that you understood** everything I asked"* but there probably isn't a single word that means a demonstration of comprehension and which is in a 1-year-old's vocabulary.

Answer (score 4):

Express your gratitude for her accommodating your request (and, optionally, share your pleasure at the outcome):

> **Thanks!** Now I have a ball — shall we throw it at baba?
>
> **Thanks!** Baba’s hair looks much nicer that way, and he says such funny things!
>
> **Thanks!** Now I can turn it on, and we’ll see baba's papers fly all over the room!
>
> **Thanks!** Let’s tell baba, too, and see how he turns all red and shouts at them to get off his car!

*Please* and *thank you* are, after all, verbal behaviors to be modelled and encouraged.

Comment: actually, I wanted to praise the fact that at such a young age she can identify and remember a ball, lizard, fan, and finally understand "statements" like 'pull baba's hair'.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius But you *are* doing that - you are providing positive reinforcement of her ability to understand language by indicating that she has done so successfully and you are pleased with that result. I suspect that one reason children seem to be (pathology aside) universally successful in learning language is that it has a built-in positive feedback loop.

Answer (score 1):

"Very good!" is my suggestion. That is the expression used by teachers of English as a foreign language to praise beginners who finally pronounce a word correctly, and they are able to understand it, and so would a very young child.